# Special css and js url about cdn for prestashop

Tags: javascript, css, url-rewriting, prestashop, cdn

Although I added cdn.website.com inside Prestashop, only jpgs are taken from cdn. I have tried tons of things to add for js and css as well but nothing worked.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

currently Prestashop does not support CDN for CSS and JS resource. You try the fix on the following bug report: http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-3849